# Is it possible to create the Docker Image for each Maven -Spring Boot Sub Module with Single docker file

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, devops

We have a requirement of creating the docker image for each Maven Sub Module(SpringBoot Based Microservice)  with Single docker file at parent Module level. In short we would like to know whether it is possible to create the docker image using single docker file.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can create a Docker Image and reuse it.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2.3.3 it's no longer required to have a Dockerfile. `mvn spring-boot:build-image` will create one.

But coming back to your question - yes you can pass -f

```
docker build -f <path to dockerfile> .
```